# dbConnect() requires specific host IP

Tags: r, postgresql

In R, I'm using the `RPostgreSQL` package to connect to my Postgres database (9.5.1). Here's the code:

```
library("RPostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), dbname="mydb", host="localhost", port=5432, user="myuser")
```

This does not work, per this message:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect myuser@localhost on dbname "mydb"
)
Calls: system.time ... .valueClassTest -> is -> is ->     postgresqlNewConnection -> .Call Execution halted
```

However, if I explicitly put in the host address instead of `localhost`, it works, i.e.

```
library("RPostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), dbname="mydb", host="15.2.52.1", port=5432, user="myuser")
```

I realize this is not much to go on, but I'd like to use `localhost` here.  I'm working on Ubuntu 14.

Comment: Sounds like your database doesn't live at localhost aka 127.0.0.1. You could do port forwarding or something to get the host address to be local host, but why?

Comment: are you able to connect with psql using -h localhost? If not, then you need to look into the pg_hba.conf file. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

Comment: Confirm postgres is running on the correct interface with `netstat -pant` (something like `tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432` and possibly `tcp6 :::5432`). If not, check postgres docs for how to specify the interface. If good, then @marceljg's is the next step: can you `psql -h localhost` (with other args as needed)?